# Loooking for dataset of proteotypic and non-proteotypic peptide

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics

I'm experimenting with peptide prediction using machine learning. I need some data for testing. I already have one dataset, but I need another one or two for verification.

I'm looking for data for a proteotypic peptide and a non-proteotypic peptide.